# Why does this discord bot tell me :kick is a nil value?

Tags: lua, bots, discord

I am extremely new to making Discord bots. I am using discordia as my library. Currently, I am making a kick command but for some reason when I attempt to kick the mentioned user, it says "bot.lua:52: attempt to call method 'kick' (a nil value)". However, if I were to attempt to kick the person who sent the message, it works just fine.

```
client:on("messageCreate", function(msg)
local content = msg.content
local member = msg.member
local channel = msg.guild
local Author = msg.author

if content:sub(1,5) == prefix.."kick" then
    local isMod = false

    local function checkIfIsMod()
        for i, v in pairs(member.roles) do
            if v.name:lower() == "admin" then
                isMod = true
            end
        end
    end

    checkIfIsMod()

    if isMod then
        print("yes")
        if #msg.mentionedUsers > 1 then

        msg:reply("Mention one user at a time!")

        elseif #msg.mentionedUsers == 0 then

        msg:reply("Mention someone!")

        elseif #msg.mentionedUsers == 1 then
        local mentioned = msg.mentionedUsers[1]


        mentioned:kick()
        msg:reply("kicked")
        end
    else
        msg:reply("You aren't a mod!")
    end
end
```

end)

Comment: I am not familiar with Discordia. I will try and mess around with it but from the documentation it looks like `kick` should be called on a member object, like the member given from the message, but `mentionedUsers` returns a list of things that are not `members`. Possibly a list of IDs? Try `msg.guild.members:get(mentionedUsers[1]):kick()` I am only guessing. I will update and write an answer with my findings later, if I get around to testing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not understand everything about Discordia, but I have read the documentation and testing and I hope to elucidate the problem now:
Every connected person has two objects known to the bot: `User` and `Member`. A user is a Discord account, a member is someone in a server. In real terms: You log into **Discord** as a **user**. You are a **member** of **multiple servers**.

You cannot kick a User, because a User is not connected to the server. A Member is. `kick` is a method of Member.

`msg.author` returns a `User`, `msg.member` returns a `Member`. You say in your post that you are able to kick the person who writes the message. You do not show this code, but I have to assume you are calling `kick` on `msg.member` since it would not work on `msg.author`.

When you mention users, they are returned as a list of IDs (`msg.mentionedUsers`). Every ID has one user, but a user can be multiple "members" across multiple servers. You need to get the member relationship between the `User` who is mentioned and the guild (server) the mention is called in. You can do this with `Guild:getMember(ID)`. You could also do this (according to the docs) with `Guild.members:get(ID)`, but this is cached. Offline members are not necessarily cached (known to the method), so I found it safer to use `Guild:getMember(ID)` (which will make an HTTP request). You can get the guild with `msg.guild` (as seen in your original code).

Here is working code that iterates over all mentioned users and kicks them. You could rework this to only kick the first person if you wish. You can put this inside your `if isMod then` statement.

```lua
for id in msg.mentionedUsers:iter() do
    local u = msg.guild:getMember(id)
    print("kicking", u.name)
    u:kick()
end
```